# how to share multiple photos with an app in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: sdk, windows-phone-8

I am trying to build an app for my Windows Phone 8 that would allow a user to upload multiple files at once. I know it is currently not possible using the PhotoChooserTask and the like.

However, I was hoping it was possible to go through the "share" approach in the photos hub. Unfortunately, based on the little research so far, my app doesn't show in the "share" list if more than one file is selected. The only apps showing when selecting more than one file seem to be the *Microsoft* ones or sorta build-in ones.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that the native launchers & choosers in WP7/WP8 don't allow for choosing multiple images. It's also true that the "Share" command associated with multiple selection of images in the photos hub doesn't offer 3rd party extensiblity.

However, why not just roll your own? Apps have access to [MediaLibrary.SavedPictures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savedpictures.aspx), [MediaLibrary.Pictures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.pictures.aspx) and [MediaLibrary.RootPictureAlbum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.rootpicturealbum.aspx) which are most of the user's photos.